# Why does runtime error show when vector is empty?

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

I have the following code, where I try to find the minimum of a vector if it has more than 0 elements, otherwise return -1.

But, when the vector is empty, I get the following runtime error:

> Vector Subscript out of range.

```
int S = 0;
string s1 = "";
int n;
cin >> n;
int c[10];
string vitamins[10];
vector <int> mask1;
for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
{
    cin >> c[i];
    cin >> vitamins[i];
}
for (int a = 0;a < (1 << n);a++)
{
    for (int b = 0;b < n;b++)
    {
        if (a & (1 << b))
        {
            s1 += vitamins[b];
            S += c[b];
        }
    }
    if(s1.find('A') != string::npos &&s1.find('B') != string::npos && s1.find('C') != string::npos)
    {
        mask1.push_back(S);
    }
    S = 0;
    s1 = "";
}
int minimum = mask1[0];
int size = mask1.size();
if(mask1.empty())
{
    cout<<-1<<endl;
}
else
{
    for (int m = 1;m < size;m++)
    {
        if (minimum > mask1[m])
        {
            minimum = mask1[m];
        }
    }
    cout << minimum << endl;
}
```

Comment: You do `int minimum = mask1[0];` before you check if the vector is empty.

Comment: Sorry for the last comment, I will try this now!

Comment: If `mask1` is empty then `int minimum = mask1[0];` is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: For future reference, using `mask1.at(0)` throws an exception, which can be handled and is easier to detect.

Comment: Also, FYI, your 1st `for` loop has buffer overflows if the user enters a value `> 10` for `n`.  Why not use `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `int[10]` and `string[10]`? Or better, since you always use `c` and `vitamins` together, then use a single `std::vector<struct>`, where the `struct` holds an `int` and a `std::string` together.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

`int minimum = mask1[0];`

You access the first index of `mask1` *before* checking if it is empty. In the case that it is empty (i.e. the size is 0), this would result in undefined behavior.

You should place this declaration *after* you check if mask1 is empty.

Comment: subscripting out of range is undefined behaviour; "results in out-of-bounds error" is misleading, as one could think that the program reacts in some defined way, e.g. by throwing an exception.